# I would like to donate my time to a 'for profit' company

Tags: internship, work-experience, education

I am a programmer with 10 months of experience (.NET) and I have some free time currently (1 month) because I'm changing my job.
I'd like to learn new things by doing some project for free just to learn new things. 
I'm interested in working on commercial projects - not in contributing to open source projects.

Any ideas/tips?

Comment: IMO: Please don't color your commentary based on personal beliefs or desires (FLOSS vs commercial/proprietary). Why the user does or does not want to do something isn't necessarily our business. He wants to do commercial and is asking for advice on that possibility.

Comment: To the OP: I actually have absolutely no advice for you at all, and here is why: I work for a large multinational company (we create hardware and software both, used by many governments and individuals across the globe, and it **does not allow under any circumstances whatsoever** donation of time to work codes, either by employees or outsiders.

Comment: Some open source have commercial-compatible licenses. For example, you can create your own private fork of Apache and work on a private customization or a plug-in module for that software. You're not obligated to donate your changes to the community, and you still retain the ability to commercialize your efforts if you choose to.

Comment: Open source and commercial are not mutually exclusive. Many well-known open source projects are backed by for-profit companies.

Comment: What is it about commercial projects that you feel is different from open source projects? Is it the teamwork aspect of working in close proximity to those with whom you will be collaborating? (That's really all I can think it could be. The software development activities are the same.)

Comment: Most commercial projects will require 1 month to get you to a point where you know the project enough to actually contribute properly.

Comment: @CGCampbell I disagree, sorry. If you spot in a question something which doesn't add up, you would better point it out, so that the asker might clarify. X/Y problems, and variations thereof, are very common.

Comment: To the OP: you didn't specify if you want to do it live or remotely.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My gut feeling here is that you're going to have to look at extremely small companies (think Mom and Pop shops) to accomplish what your trying.

From a practical standpoint; you only have 1 month.  By the time you look around and find a place willing to take you in; that company would need to do all the paperwork to make you 'legal'; procure a working environment/supplies; etc.  And for all this; they only get you for 1 month max.

And while not a knock on your experience; but for a programmer with only 10 months experience; I'd expect that it would take you about 3 months to get caught up to speed (coding standards, process workflow, general onboarding, etc.)

Given all of the above; if I was making the call as to whether to bring you on; the effort involved far outweighs any benefits I'd be able to get out of you for only a month.

If I were you; I'd probably take another look at open source, possibly do some freelancing; or just enjoy your month off, recharge, and get ready to hit the ground running at your new job.

Comment: Or looking at it another way, a junior programmer working for nothing is an "unpaid intern" (perhaps slightly overqualified by the 10 months experience, depending what the prospective supervisor thinks of it). So we're looking for a 1-month unpaid internship. Probably aren't many around, but if there are any with large companies then that's probably what they'll be called.

Comment: And then there's the time needed by a regular staff member to induct, supervise, and verify any work done, and the value of having a one month intern very quickly diminishes.

Answer (score 7):

Just work on something on your own, this not only shows initiative and interest in the field but will also give you the best experience possible (building all aspects of something from the ground up). .NET let's you build things pretty efficiently and easily, figure out what type of commercial products your interested in and just take a look at some and build similar functionality/systems that these products have.

Best way to learn is to just go after it yourself.

Comment: Everyone loves a go-getter.